# How do force phpmyadmin to show structure with empty table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just updated to version 4.1.7.  I've noticed that when I select a table thats empty, it doesn't show me the structure by default.  Instead I get something that says:

`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0002 sec)`

Is there a way to force the Structure tab to load first instead of table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, clicking the table name in the navigation area takes you to the Browse view; clicking the icon in front of it takes you to the Structure view.

You can change those defaults with [`$cfg['NavigationTreeDefaultTabTable']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeDefaultTabTable) and [`$cfg['DefaultTabTable']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_DefaultTabTable).

Comment: Thanks Issac.  That works quite well!  But before I close the question, is there no way to make phpmyadmin discern between an empty table (preferred structure tab) and a table with data (preferred browse tab)?

Comment: No, that feature doesn't currently exist.